# URL History in Flask application

Tags: backbone.js, flask

I have a flask application and using some intergration with backbone. But I cannot use backbone router because of the flask wsgi.But I want to have the backbone router history mechanism for this application. I know I can use google analytics but that is a separate thing. I want to have a record of all the urls browsed and want flask to record it.how can i do that ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use backbone route because of flask wsgi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution for recording every url from server side in Flask is a `@before_request` handler

```
@before_request
def log_url():
  save(request.url)
```